# How to find the distribution from a given form of generating function

Tags: probability-distributions, generating-functions

I have the generating function defined by F(x)= $\sum P(n,s) x^n$ . And the expression for F(x) is given by $F(x)= e^{\frac{a}{b}x} (1-x)^{b/s}$.
Then how can i find p(n,s) function..? Can anybody solve this problem.?

Comment: Taylor series are unique, so if $F(x)$ is generating function, it's Taylor series aroud $0$ should provide you with probabilities $P(n,s)$. Above sum must be taken from $n=0$ to $n=\infty$.

Comment: Yiu can find some theory [Here](http://www.am.qub.ac.uk/users/g.gribakin/sor/Chap3.pdf) . Given $A(s)$ whicn is known to be PGF, one can obtain $p_k=P(X=k)$ either by expanding $A(s)$ in a power series or differentiating $A(s)$ $k$ times with respect to $s$ and setting $s=0$.

Comment: There is no simple expression for $P(n, s)$.

Comment: even a power series expansion solution will be of great help